# Is a 3 prong single outlet receptacle currently manufactured?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

My house was built in 1939.  Since it's a timber frame, there are a lot of single 2 prong outlets that are recessed into the posts. These are located near the floor, so the wiring is then feed up from the bottom thru a hole in the beam.

I can replace the old two wire with Romex™ by fishing it thru the existing hole, however, I would like to find something that requires minimal work to fit into the existing pocket of the beam.

The current receptacle has H-H&H marking on it

Does anyone know if someone currently manufactures a *single* 3-prong outlet that would be similar to my current 2-prong outlets?

Here are some pics
[image]

[image]

Comment: Consider whether enlaging the hole to fit a modern box will damage the load bearing capabilities of the beam (which may have already been compromised by the original installation). A surface mounted box on the beam itself may be a much easier and better choice.

Comment: So long as you are putting money and effort into this, I suggest you find an electrician or someone knowledgeable to help you plan how to upgrade the electrics in your home without being constrained by the way 80-year-old wires have been routed.    If you don't have hollow walls, look into using metal not plastic cables and surface mounted boxes.

Answer (score 11):

**Compact Nema 5-15R** in a search engine turned up this current product that looks like the grandchild of yours

[image: image from gordonelectricsupply.com, no endorsement implied]

LEVITON 5279-C WHITE FLANGED OUTLET-NM5-15R

**flanged Nema 5-15R** turns up additional results, based on the description of this one as "flanged"

Comment: Nice find! I wonder, though, if the "box" into which the OPs outlets are currently installed are considered usable by modern code. i.e., if updating with new NM-B and these outlets, is that considered enough of an update to require "upgrading" the box in which it's all wired, and if so, is a compatible box available. (I'd like to think that Leviton makes a box into which one could install their outlet.)

Comment: @FreeMan A lot of those "flanged" type outlets are intended to be panel-mounted on a machine and not mounted in a wall, so a well-tailored box would likely be hard to find.  I've seen some manufacturers sell a mounting plate that lets you install one in a standard-sized wall box, but that doesn't help OP much.

Answer (score 4):

There *may* be something available, but I doubt it. 15A/20A receptacles are almost all designed now to fit a standard single-gang box. Even single receptacles are usually on a yoke designed for a single-gang box (they are useful because there are times where a dedicated circuit for a single device is required). Plus, as I found when replacing receptacles in my house, even some single-gang boxes from many years ago are not quite big enough for modern receptacles, and all the more so if you want to put in GFCI or a smart switch or anything else special.

Just get a small metal box and a standard clamp. Screw the box into the wood. Run the NM cable (Romex) into the back of the box through the clamp and you're all set. Something like [this Handy Box](https://www.homedepot.com/p/4-in-H-x-2-in-W-x-1-7-8-in-D-Gray-1-Gang-Drawn-Handy-Box-with-Eight-1-2-in-KO-s-Raised-Ground-TS-Bracket-1-Pack-662/100557445):

[image: Handy Box]

but there are plenty of choices. Plus you get two receptacles for the price of one (look for receptacles with screw-to-clamp, and remember, friends don't let friends use backstabs).

Comment: This is probably the most practical answer, but it's certainly an ugly option. Hard to know whether to vote _for_ practicality or _against_ ugly, so I'll abstain.

Answer (score 4):

[System 22](https://22system.com/) might work for you, longest reach is 1 1/4" deep but it seems some images of the installation are in concrete walls so maybe there is a way to make it work.

They are super pricey though.

[image: System 22 Boccee]

Comment: The price on these is absolutely insane! $170 for a single! I suspect someone buying in bulk (boutique hotel?) would get substantial discounts, but still. In any case, this actually requires an ordinary box *behind* the wall, so it won't actually solve OP's problem which isn't to make a fancy flush-mount minimalist look on the wall but rather to embed into the beam in the existing location.

Comment: Yeah I only see 1 1/4" being the max depth before you hit the box but it seems unlikely the concrete walls are less than 1 1/4" in depth so I am not sure how those installs are done.

Comment: On the concrete I suspect they made a mold for the receptacle and the box and poured around it.

Comment: Be nice if they could make a trimable barrel "box" that could hold the bocce outlet and a faceplate that could lock it only a standard single gang to give flexibility on depth.  Kind of a niche item though so won't be holding my breath.  The whole nec ul/csa outlet options seems very single dimensional without variety so it is nice to see something different even if they are expensive.

Comment: I can't see how this could meet code unless the box was accessible from the other side of the wall. Need a sledgehammer tp "access" the box...

Comment: Looking at the finish differences around those two receptacles, @Ecnerwal, it looks like a sledgehammer has been involved here at some point.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a longshot, and you should definitely check for code compliance, but I found this at my local (German!) supplier:

[image: Jung NEMA15 A]
[Jung NEMA15 A](https://www.jung-group.com/de-DE/Steckdose-US-Norm-NEMA-15-A-alpinweiss/A-521-15-WW)

This is meant to be installed on a European style electrical box (again, check compliance) which are round and about 70mm in diameter.

They are, being an odd item for a German brand, not very cheap though.

Comment: What a strange object — how are you supposed to provide 120V to this receptacle in Germany?

Comment: @JacobKrall: it is strange indeed, I guess there are some edge-cases where you are expected to install an extra transformer?

Comment: Split the wire in half, lengthwise, @JacobKrall! (No, that's a joke, don't do that. Really, _please_ don't try to do that!!!)